# How to combine the data from two different dataframes with pyspark?

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, amazon-emr

I have two different (and very large) dataframes (details below). And I need to merge the data from both of them. Since these dataframes are huge (with millions of rows in the first one and thousands in the second one), I was trying to use the AWS EMR service. But I don't quite understand how it is done there and the tutorials I've seen mostly show the instructions for one dataframe only. So, I've been wondering how I can use pyspark for two different dataframes.

Here are the details:

The first dataframe, say `df`, contains data about the people watching tv on different days. It looks like this:

```
    id     date     other_data

0   0   2020-01-01  some data
1   1   2020-02-01  some data
2   2   2020-03-01  some data
3   3   2020-04-01  some data
4   4   2020-05-01  some data
```

Here, `id` is the id of the watcher, `date` is the date of watching, `other_data` contains other information (like the duration of watching, channel, etc.)

The second dataframe, say `program`, contains data about the programs. It looks like this:

```
       date      program    start_time  end_time

0   2020-01-01  program 1   14:00:00    15:00:00
1   2020-01-01  program 2   15:00:00    16:00:00
2   2020-01-01  program 3   16:00:00    17:00:00
3   2020-01-01  program 4   17:00:00    18:00:00
4   2020-01-01  program 5   18:00:00    19:00:00
```

Here, `date` is the date, `program` is the name of the program, `start_time` and `end_time` are the time of the program's beginning and end.

Basically, what I need to do is to create one dataframe that would contain all the information from both of these dataframes. I need this final dataframe to have a separate row for each user and each program. In other words, I need a dataframe that would duplicate each row in the first dataframe for each of the programs on the same day.

It might seem a little bit confusing, but here is an example of the final dataframe I want to receive:

```
    id     date     other_data   program    start_time  end_time

0   0   2020-01-01  some data   program 1   14:00:00    15:00:00
1   0   2020-01-01  some data   program 2   15:00:00    16:00:00
2   0   2020-01-01  some data   program 3   16:00:00    17:00:00
3   0   2020-01-01  some data   program 4   17:00:00    18:00:00
4   0   2020-01-01  some data   program 5   18:00:00    19:00:00
```

As you can see, this final dataframe contains the data for each user and each program that was shown on the same day this user watched tv. In this particular case, the user with `id=0` has watched tv on `01/01/2020`. On the same day, `program 1`, `program 2`, `program 3`, `program 4`, and `program 5` were shown. So, I need to have one row for each of the programs with their details. And, of course, I need the data from the first dataframe (contained in `other_data`).

So far, I created the following approach: I iterate over the first dataframe, for each row I find all the rows in the second dataframe that have the same date, merge it and add to the third (final) dataframe.

Here is the code I use:

```
ids = []  # users' id
dates = []  # dates
other_data = []  # other data from the first dataframe 
programs = []  # all programs
start_times = []  # starting times
end_times = []  # ending times

for i, row in df.iterrows():
    temp = program.loc[program['date'] == row['date']]  # find all programs on the same date
    
    for j, program_row in temp.iterrows():  # iterate over the programs on the same date
        # append all the info
        ids.append(row['id'])
        dates.append(row['date'])
        other_data.append(row['other_data'])
        programs.append(program_row['program'])
        start_times.append(program_row['start_time'])
        end_times.append(program_row['end_time'])
        
# create final dataframe
final = pd.DataFrame({'id': ids, 'date': dates, 'other_data': other_data, 'program': programs, 
                      'start_time': start_times, 'end_time': end_times})
```

This approach is working, but it is extremely slow (considering the large size of dataframes). I was, therefore, wondering how to split this job between several workers using `ERM` by AWS. If I understand it correctly, I need to split the first dataframe `df` between workers, and, at the same time, provide them with the full `program` dataframe. Is it possible to do that? And how?

Would appreciate any help or advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that both df and program are Pandas dataframes and merging/joining is the action needed, see [pandas.DataFrame.merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html). Try this:

```
import pandas as pd

finial = pd.merge(df, program, on=['date'], how='inner')
```

In case the Pandas version is too slow, you could convert the dataframes to PySPark dataframes and perform the following steps:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("convert").getOrCreate()

df_spark = spark.createDataFrame(df)
program_spark = spark.createDataFrame(program)

final_spark = df_spark.join(F.broadcast(program), on=['date'], how='inner')
```

Here, it is assumed that the dataframe program is a small dataframe - if not, please remove the broadcast.

Hopefully, it is solving your issue and removing the slow loops here.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a try and get back to you!

Comment: It helped, thanks! Just out of curiosity, how would I do that without `join` in spark?

Comment: You are welcome. Without join: A good question. Please see [Optimize Spark Joins Unfashionably](https://flomin-dan.medium.com/optimizing-your-spark-joins-in-an-unfashionable-manner-e273ede0ca13) for a specific example/use case where joining was replaced by an udf and withColumn operation.

Comment: Thanks! I'll give it a look